# Golang Appengine - How to serve a static file from root url

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I tried to deploy my go app to appengine and it complains that my root url isn't handled on the server. My app.yml file is set up to serve index.html when the root url is hit. It seems to work locally. Is there something wrong with this approach? Here's my yaml file. Thanks!

```
application: myapp-go
version: 2
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: js_app/index.html
  upload: js_app/uploads/.*

- url: /api/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /javascripts
  static_dir: js_app/javascripts/

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: js_app/stylesheets/

- url: /templates
  static_dir: js_app/templates/

- url: /images
  static_dir: js_app/images/
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler is not seeing your `index.html` in your `uploads` directory that corresponds with the given `url` and `static_files`. Use this instead:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: js_app/index.html
  upload: js_app/index.html
```

If you have other static files you want to make available under the `uploads` route I'll suggest you separate them to be:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: js_app/index.html
  upload: js_app/index.html

- url: /uploads
  static_dir: js_app/uploads/
```